# How does the __block specifier work?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, objective-c-blocks

I can specify an a variable on stack with a `__block` specifier and then I am able to modify it in a block. I am just wondering, behind the scenes what happens? (If the block is executed sometime in the future, then the stack might be cleared)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a block which references a `__block` variable is copied, the variable is moved to the heap.  This means that all code which references it has to do so through an indirect means, basically a pointer, so that, when it moves from the stack to the heap, those references can switch along with it.

This is documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH6-SW6).